# On the theory of moving series inside integrals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I'm working on my bachelor's thesis on the Gibbs phenomenon and in one of my sources the following step is made during a proof of the existence of the Gibbs phenomenon for the ramp function:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}\cos(nt)\,\mathrm{d}t
=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\int_{0}^{x} \left( \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(kt)\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
- \frac{x}{2}\,.
$$
For some reason, I can't for the life of me figure out what the author did here. Obviously the series was moved inside of the integral, but where do the $\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{x}{2}$ come from? Was a specific trig identity used here or what?

Any help or suggestions on possible sources to consult would be much appreciated.

Comment: Integrating $1/2$ from 0 to $x$ gives.....what?

Comment: @shashi That is easy enough, but I'm especially baffled by the 1/2. From my point of view it just magically appears out of nowhere. Where does it come from in the first place? I have to admit my trig skills are a bit rusty and the answer might lie there.

Comment: Did you do the integration of $1/2$ form $0$ to $x$? It gives you $x/2$ and that cancels with $-x/2$ so the author did "nothing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\frac12$ and $\frac x2$ cancel, so I think that's a separate step to what the author did. It's a standard trick to add something, then subtract the same thing to make other simplifications possible down the line. My guess is that this is the reason for this manouver: either the $\frac12$ or the $\frac x2$ is going to be useful to simplify something else a few lines down.

As to the sum and integral, $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty$ by definition means $\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n = 1}^k$ (and then for some reason he swapped $n$ and $k$ around). In any of these finite sums, you can without problem swap the order of $\sum$ and $\int$. What you can't do is change the order of $\int$ and $\lim$.

Comment: Ahh, the "add the null element" trick. I'm going to see if that works and I end up with the same result.

Comment: Yup, that was it.